Class added programmatically responds differently
I'm trying to apply a jQuery .load process to a div, referencing a class that was added programmatically. I can get the .load process to work properly when referencing a hardcoded class (ie applied in the backend), but when I use the programmatic class, I get a blank.
The code I'm working with looks something like this. I put them into separate functions, since the first responds to an opening click, and the second is an ajax form submit.
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var targetID = $('.clickfield').data('id');
        $('.clickfield' + targetID).click(function() {
          if (!$('.refreshdiv' + targetID).hasClass("testrefresh")) {
           $('.refreshdiv' + targetID).addClass("testrefresh");
           }
        });
     });
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.formsubmitaction form .form-submit').click(function () {
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (typeof settings !== 'undefined' && settings.extraData && settings.extraData._drupal_ajax) {
             $('.testrefresh').load(location.href + " .testrefresh > *");
         }
       }
     );
  });
})(jQuery);

This works perfectly if I use a fixed class ('.refresh') but the loaded content is blank if I use .testrefresh, which was added programmatically
I'm assuming this has something to do with the class being added on the clientside where it's not connecting to the server side.  How do I direct the programmatic class reload properly?
edit:
Also tried setting the click to an on function, with the same results:
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.formsubmitaction form .form-submit', function(){
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (typeof settings !== 'undefined' && settings.extraData && settings.extraData._drupal_ajax) {
             $('.testrefresh').load(location.href + " .testrefresh > *");
         }
      });
  });
})(jQuery);


which was added programmatically-> What do you mean? Is the class added before DOM is rendered, or are you adding them dynamically after HTML is rendered?

Also load(location.href + " .testrefresh > *"); looks fishy to me. for example, it will create a URL like abc.com/.testrefresh > *. I don't know what kind of URL it is?

@Death-is-the-real-truth load(location.href + " .testrefresh > *") will split the url so it does $(el).load(location.href").done(r => $(el).html($("<div>").append(r).find(".testrefresh > *").html()) (or so).  So will add >* to the source element, which doesn't seem correct, should just be $('.testrefresh').load(location.href + " .testrefresh"); - it's unclear if that's the actual issue though.

Given the above, you should be able to see that, when the page content loads via ajax, the .testrefresh>* applies to the content that's just been loaded via ajax - this clearly won't have any client-side click event changes applied.  It looks like you might have multiple forms and need to know which was to apply to.  Would the content being loaded be different?  You should probably pass some sort of data id to identify which data is being loaded (and then you can also reduce the server-side html being generated to just the html that's required rather than the whole page)

To clarify:  ".testrefresh > *" - it's unclear if the >* has an impact, probably not as OP says the works with fixed data.  The issue is that .testrefresh is not present on the data being loaded.

Thanks, for the info. Regarding the load syntax, >*  loads just the div contents, which can help with nesting issues in some cases, namely mine. @fdomn-m is correct that the actual problem stems from having multiple similar divs on the page, so I'm trying to identify and act on the one that's being updated, hence tagging it with a new class. But clearly that won't work.

Given that the editable field is already updating the data serverside and the display div will update correctly when the page is reloaded later, does it make sense to just use jquery to rewrite the display div with the editable field value? This would allow the user to see that the data is updated, and it saves transaction effort to fetch the updated value from the server.

Are you missing a plus symbol, and maybe a quotation mark?
$('.'clickfield + targetID).click(function() {
          if (!$('.refreshdiv' + targetID).hasClass("testrefresh")) {
           $('.refreshdiv + targetID).addClass("testrefresh");
           }
        });

vs.
$('.' + clickfield + targetID).click(function() {
          if (!$('.refreshdiv' + targetID).hasClass("testrefresh")) {
           $('.refreshdiv' + targetID).addClass("testrefresh");
           }
        });


Great catch, but no - I slipped a bit on the copy/paste. Fixed the example.
